# Partition function computation on a Riemannian Manifold

Tags: quantum-field-theory, string-theory, supersymmetry, sigma-models

This discussion comes from Chapter 10, Mirror Symmetry.

I am given a Riemannian manifold $M$, and a classical (Euclidean) theory:
$$(1)\quad
S_E={\int}_0^\beta d\tau\space\Bigl(\frac{1}{2}g_{ij}{\dot{\phi}}^i{\dot{\phi}}^j+g_{ij}{\bar{\psi}}^iD_\tau\psi^j+\frac{1}{4}R_{ijkl}\psi^i\psi^j\bar{\psi}^k\bar{\psi}^l\Bigr),
$$
where:
$$(2)\quad
D_\tau\psi^i=\partial_\tau\psi^i+\dot{\phi}^j\Gamma^i_{jk}\psi^k.
$$
The theory admits the following SUSY transformation:

$$(3)\quad\delta\phi^i=\epsilon{\bar{{\psi}}}^i-\bar{\epsilon}\psi^i,\quad \delta\psi^i=\epsilon\Bigl(-\dot{\phi}^i-\Gamma^i_{jk}\bar{\psi}^j\psi^k\Bigr),\quad\delta\bar{\psi}^i=\bar{\epsilon}\Bigl(\dot{\phi}^i-\Gamma^i_{jk}\bar{\psi}^j\psi^k\Bigr).
$$
The index is given by the following path integral:
$$(4)\quad
Tr(-1)^F=\int_{PBCs} DxD\bar{\psi}D\psi\space exp\Bigl(-S_E\Bigr).
$$
By the localization principle, this path integral will localize to the vicinity of the stationary points of the transformation in $(3)$. This comes out to be the origin of the coordinate chart, and corresponds to the zero loci in the phase space integral on the RHS of $(4)$. Let's label the origin $P$, then calculation shows that:
$$(5)\quad
Tr(-1)^F=\Biggl[\frac{(-1)^{n/2}}{2^n(n/2)!(\pi)^{n/2}}\int_pdVR_{i_1j_1k_1l_1}|_p\dots R_{i_{n/2}j_{n/2}k_{n/2}l_{n/2}}|_p\epsilon^{i_1j_1\dots i_{n/2}j_{n/2}}\epsilon^{k_1l_1\dots k_{n/2}l_{n/2}}\Biggr].
$$
The subscript $P$ emphasizes the fact that the integration on the manifold be restricted to the vicinity of $P$. If I was to be able to extend this integration to the whole of $M$, then what would be realized in the square brackets is just the formula for the Euler number of the manifold: $\chi(M)$, and things would make perfect sense. However the issue is this:

**I am not being able to provide the argument for extending this integration to the whole of $M$.**

Apparently, one can argue along the following lines: $(5)$ gives the contribution to the index coming from the vicinity of $P\in M$, then to get the "full index" one must sum the contributions coming from all $P\in M$. The problem here is that $(4)$ defines the "full index" in the first place, and this is what (by the localization principle) simplifies to $(5)$.

Can someone please help out?